# Android Galaxy Tab Search button causes problem

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created the android application for both android phones and galaxy tab, in default  search button at the bottom  of the Tab, while hitting web service  when i click the search button ,the progress is stopped  , my application getting collapsed ,but it is working fine when I don`t click that button.

I need to handle search button in galaxy tab.How can I handle that? . Because that button is not present in mobile phone.

If anyone know the solution help me out?

Thanks.

Comment: most android devices have a search button; it's left out on some of the latest devices, though

Comment: I love the questions that didn't provide more information like code, error messages and stack traces. Please provide enough information to help you. Something like `my application getting collapsed` is not helpful...

Answer (score 0):

using the following code block i can handle that button,

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
        return true; // or false (obviously?)
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```